# Lifelines boolean index in Python did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 88 but corresponding boolean dimension is 76

Tags: python, pandas, cox-regression, cox, lifelines

This very simple piece of code,

```
# imports...
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter
import pandas as pd

src_file = "Pred.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(src_file, header=0, delimiter=',')
df = df.drop(columns=['score'])

cph = CoxPHFitter()
cph.fit(df, duration_col='Length', event_col='Status', show_progress=True)
```

produces an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:/Users/.../predictor.py", line 11,
>   in 
>       cph.fit(df, duration_col='Length', event_col='Status', show_progress=True)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\hrpred\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py",
>   line 298, in fit
>       self._check_values(df)
>
> File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\hrpred\lib\site-packages\lifelines\fitters\coxph_fitter.py",
>   line 323, in _check_values
>       cols = str(list(X.columns[low_var]))
>
> File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\hrpred\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 1754, in _ _ getitem _ _
>
> result = getitem(key)
>
> **IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 88 but corresponding
>   boolean dimension is 76**

However, when I print **df** itself, everything's all right. As you can see, everything is inside the library. And the library's examples work fine.

Comment: We would require to have the files that you are using here to find out what exactly is going wrong. Could you maybe provide an example that does not use external files?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I cannot provide the file cause it contains the proprietary info. But file is processed perfectly with pandas, I can print and slice data. Is the root of the problem in pandas or CoxPHFitter (lifelines)?

Comment: If not the data itself, can you provide the following information: columns in dataframe, the dtype of each column, and the number of null and not-null values in each column. e.g. `df.columns`, `df[column1].dtype`, `sum(df[column1].isnull())`, and `sum(df[column1].notnull())` (for each column). It sounds like indexes aren't being aligned which makes me wonder about null/NaN values.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your data look like - I had the same error, which was resolved when I removed all but the duration, event and coefficient(s) from the pandas df I was using. That is, I had a lot of extra columns in the df that were confusing the cox PH fitter since you don't actually specify which coef you want to include as an argument to cph.fit().